# Enter a number with up to 9 digits (less than 1 billion). Using Python, Print numbers to letters

Tags: python

I am learning Python. Having trouble at this exercise. The question is: Enter a number with up to 9 digits (less than 1 billion). Using Python, Print numbers to letters.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What does it mean *Print numbers to letters*?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `int` to `str` :

```
for i in str(a):
    print(i)
```

In this function, `str(a)` converts the int `a` to a string. The in the for, you iterates over all its digits.

Another way to print the digits of an int is to use successive euclidean divisions.

Hope this helps :)